# Alternative way of expressing a quantied statement with "Some"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, recreational-mathematics

I am reading about formulation of equivalent statements.
E.g.
All $A$ are $B$ $\equiv$ There are no $A$ that are not $B$
There is one specific case, that I am a bit confused, specifically the equivalent of the statement

> Some $A$ are $B$ e.g. Some people are bigots

The first alternative that I thought about of the statement was:

> Not all $A$ are $B$ i.e. Not all people are bigots

This to me seems correct, but the alternative proposed by a solution I am reading is:

> There exists at least one A is a B i.e. at least one person is a bigot

So now I am thinking if the statement I came up with is some sort of tautology. I can understand that the proposed expression seems to "convey" more information, but I would like some help to understand if there are any issues with the statement I came up with that are eluding me

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Presumably, while there may be some people who are not bigots, there are no bigots who are not people.  Thus one of your sets should be wholly included in the other.

Comment: And the statement "some people are bigots"  does not imply that there are people who are not bigots.  It is silent on that point.

Comment: @lulu: Is my Venn diagram wrong? I am confused if the issue is about the natural language i.e. people/bigots or the actual sets A/B. I think I didn't get your point completely

Comment: It is wrong, or at least misleading, in that in contemplates the possibility that there are some $A$ which are not $B$ and some $B$ which are not $A$.  One of those inclusions is impossible and that impossibility should be reflected in the diagram.

Comment: @lulu: `there are no bigots who are not people` makes sense, but if we say `Some $A$ are $B$` how is that information conveyed?

Comment: In words, by saying that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$.  Or, since $B\subseteq A$, just by saying $B\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @lulu: Does the statement `Some $A$ are $B$` somehow imply that all $B$ are $A$?

Comment: Of course.  But in this case, we know that *all* $B$ are $A$.

Comment: @lulu: So the formal proposition depends on the english example? I thought that what the statement `Some $A$ are $B$` implies does not depend on what $A$ or $B$ is

Comment: What formal proposition?  i don't see a formal proposition here.  You chose an example, and I am working with that example.

Comment: It is easy to come up with different examples.  Say $C$ is the set of people and $D$ is the set of things that weigh more than $200$ pounds.  Then there are some $C$ that are $D$ but there are also $C$ that are not $D$ and $D$ that are not $C$.

Comment: Right, so $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$.  Fine.  But in the example you chose, it is also true that $B\subseteq A$.  That fact makes your diagram misleading at best.

Comment: @lulu: I see what you mean. I am removing it then

Comment: Consider the statement "Some women are bigots."  Then your diagram is fine, because some bigots aren't women.  The statement "Some people is are bigots" is different because all bigots are people.  Technically the diagram is still correct, but as lulu has already said, it's misleading.

Comment: @lulu: So the venn diagram I presented was just one case/example that could apply on a statement `Some $A$ are $B$` right?

Comment: @saulspatz: So there are $2$ venn diagrams for the case of `Some $A$ are $B$` depending on the relationship of $B$ to $A$ right?

Comment: I removed it as my question was not really about the venn diagram but I can see that it also contributed to my confusion

Comment: But then, what is the question?  Knowing that $A\cap B$ is non-empty does not tell you whether or not there are $A$ that are not $B$ nor if there are $B$ that are not $A$. It does, however, tell us that $A$, $B$, and $A\cap B$ are all non-empty.

Comment: @lulu: `does not tell you whether or not there are  that are not ` if some $A$ are $B$ does that not imply that some $A$ are *not* $B$?

Comment: At least two, I'd say.  We could have a third diagram for the case $A\cap B=\emptyset$, where the statement is false. A Venn diagram is just an informal tool, though a very useful one.  We use the diagram to try to determine what's true, but the diagram itself isn't a proof.  Still, the diagram should reflect the situation as closely as possible, so that it doesn't lead us to jumping to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: @Jim  Absolutely not.  it is entirely silent on that point.

Comment: @lulu: that's interesting, because at least in natural language it comes to my mind that if "some are" then it logically follows that "some are not" otherwise we accept the case that "some are" includes the possibility of "all are". I guess there lies my error?

Comment: @saulspatz: I can't think of the case you are describing. Could you help with an example?

Comment: @Jim "Some cats are mathematicians."

Comment: @Jim  In mathematical language, knowing that some $A$ are $B$ just means that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$.  Nothing more, nothing less.  I agree that in ordinary language the phrase is ambiguous..."some of my students failed that test' would generally suggest that some students passed, but even then it would be better to spell it out.

Comment: @saulspatz: It didn't occur to me to use invalid statements. But in this case, I can't think of what the Venn diagram would be, since the statement is false and neither of the sets are part of the other

Comment: @lulu: So it could also mean "all students failed that test"? And is there a third possibility?

Comment: @Jim I wouldn't statement is invalid, merely false.  To me, "invalid" would mean that it isn't a statement at all, like "Are you happy?"  At any rate, the Venn diagram would be two disjoint circles.

Comment: @Jim Mathematically, of course it could.  And it would allow for the possibilities that someone else's students passed or failed.  It simply doesn't say anything about those cases.

Comment: @lulu: Hence `Not all  are  ` is wrong because it is $\equiv$ to `some $A$ are not $B$`?

Comment: It's not that it is wrong, we just have no idea whether or not it is true.  "Some perfect numbers are even" is certainly true but nobody knows whether "all perfect numbers are even" is true or not.

Comment: @lulu: hence we don't know the truth of the statement: `Not all perfect numbers are even`. Which is my proposition in the post. Is this right?

Comment: Yes.  Just logically, knowing that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$ tells us nothing at all about $A\cap B^c$ or $A^c\cap B$.  Of course, in any precise example it may be possible to say more, but that depends on properties of the example.

Comment: @lulu: What is that notation $c$ on top of $B$?

Comment: It means "complement".  Thus $B^c$ would be the set of things in the universe which are not in $B$.  If $A$ is the set of perfect integers and $B$ is the set of even integers, then $A\cap B^c$ would be the set of odd, perfect integers and $A^c\cap B$ would be the set of imperfect even integers.

Comment: @lulu: So is the following summary correct? If the statement "Some A are B" is true, the statement "Not all A are B" is not equivalent to it, because we do not know if it is true or false. And if 2 statements are equivalent they must have the same value. It could be the case that i) "All A are B" is true which is consistent with "Some A are B" and hence "Not all A are B" is false or ii) "Some A are not B" is true which implies "Not all A are B" is true. So due to these (2) cases we can't know if "Not all A are B" is true or false and hence the statement can not be equivalent to "Some A are B".

Comment: @lulu: Are there other cases besides the $2$ mentioned above in my summary?

Comment: What you wrote is hard to follow.  Why on earth would you imagine that "some $A$ are $B$" should be equivalent to "not all $A$ are $B$"?  Those are radically different statements.

Comment: @lulu: "Some A are B" $\equiv$ "Some A are not B" $\equiv$ "Not all A are B". That was my idea originally till you pointed out that we can not deduce the truth of "Some A are not B" if "Some A are B" is known to be true. What do you mean by "radically different statements"? Doesn't the sequence in my first sentence make sense? Or is that also wrong?

Comment: As I have said, the first statement is not equivalent to the other two.

Comment: @lulu: The reason that it is not equivalent is because we can not establish the truth of "Some A are not B" right? I am trying to make sure I understood your comments and summarizing.

Comment: @lulu: I am confused now. What I understood was that if "Some A are B" is true, since "Some A are not B" is not known if it is true or false, then the statements are not equivalent (in the sense that we can replace one for another and have the same meaning). But now with your last comment, I am getting the feeling I misunderstood your points

Comment: You keep asking the same question over and over and I keep giving you the same answer.  Saying "Some $A$ are $B$" is not the same as saying "some $A$ are not $B$".   They are different claims.  If I tell you that some of the people over there are doctors, that is not the same as saying that some people over there are not doctors.

Comment: @lulu: If we have the statement "Some people over there are doctors". It could be that either 1) *all* people over there are doctors or 2) some people over there are not doctors. Is there another case I am missing?

Comment: Yes, those are the only two cases.

Comment: @lulu: And since both (1) and (2) are supersets of "Some people over there are doctors" and we can't know if (1) or (2) is true we cant make assume any other implication about the original statement. Does this sum it up correctly?

Comment: Enough. I really can't answer the same question any more times.  If what I've said already doesn't answer that, then I don't think I can find effective words.